# using MvcMailer in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcmailer

We're creating an app that uses ASP.NET MVC4 for the web app and WCF for the web services that access a common data store.

The web app send emails using MvcMailer, I was hoping someone could point me to some resources that show how MvcMailer can be used from WCF as well (if the said resources exist).

I've gone through: https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/issues/44

I'd rather not roll my own code, but I'm willing to go down that path if there's no better solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was the guy who posted that issue on GitHub. There are no resources out there right now for doing that, so I had to figure it out myself. Here's the little guide I wrote to my co-workers. I should post it online somewhere.

How to allow MvcMailer to function in your WCFService.

1) Enable the HttpContext

A) Add the following to your Web.Config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />   
</system.serviceModel>
```

B) Add the following attribute to your service class.

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
//public class MyService
//{
//  ...
//}
```

2) Enable Razor

A) Add the following to your Web.Config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        </assemblies>
        <buildProviders>
            <add extension=".cshtml" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider, System.Web.WebPages.Razor"/>
        </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

B) Add the following references to the WCF service project.

```
System.Web.WebPages
System.Web.WebPages.Razor
```

C) Select the references, right click, and open Properties for them. Then set the following property:

```
Copy Local = true
```

Done! MvcMailer will now work in your WCF service!

Comment: Glad I could be of help.